# why re.findall behaves weird way as compared with re.search

Tags: python-3.x

Scenario 1: Works as expected

```
>>> output = 'addr:10.0.2.15'
>>> regnew = re.search(r'addr:(([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+)',output)
>>> print(regnew)
<re.Match object; span=(0, 14), match='addr:10.0.2.15'>
>>> print(regnew.group(1))
10.0.2.15
```

Scenario 2: Works as expected

```
>>> regnew = re.findall(r'addr:([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)',output)
>>> print(regnew)
['10.0.2.15']
```

Scenario 3: Does not work as expected. Why is the output not ['10.0.2.15']?

```
>>> regnew = re.findall(r'addr:([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+',output)
>>> print(regnew)
['2.']
```

Comment: Please use the code formatting options to make your question more readable.

Comment: In your third scenario, consider what *group* you're matching; `findall` works for groups in the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is not correct for what you want:

```
import re
output = 'addr:10.0.2.15'
regnew = re.findall(r'addr:((?:[0-9]+.){3}[0-9]+)', output)
print(regnew)
```

Notice what it changed is that I wrapped with parenthesis the full IP address, and added '?:' for the first part of the address. '?:' means it is a [non capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). [findall()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) as stated in the docs, gives a list of captured groups, that is why you want that '(?:[0-9]+.)' as non capturing group and you want to have the whole thing in a group.

Answer (score 0):

The difference here between findall and everything else is that findall returns capture groups by default (if any are present) instead of the entire matched expression.

A quick fix would be to simply change your repeated group to a noncapturing group, so findall will return the full match rather than the last result in your capture group.

```
addr:(?:[0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+
```

That will of course include `addr:` in your match. To get just the IP address, wrap both the pattern and quantifier in a capture group.

```
addr:((?:[0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+)
```